# Best Way to SELECT subset of properties for associated @Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to choose the properties of associated entities that will be loaded.

For example:

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
public class Book {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first")
    private String first;

    @Column(name = "second")
    private String second;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Page> pages = new ArrayList();
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
public class Page {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "number")
    private Integer number;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    private Book book;
}
```

I would like to have just a SELECT on the Book's first and the content of all associated Page entities

```
book
   - first
   - pages
     - content
```

For example, in PostgreSQL this might look something like

```
SELECT book.first,
       array_agg(page.content || ' ')

FROM book

LEFT JOIN page
       ON page.book_id = book.id

GROUP BY book.first
```

I've done my research on how you could go about doing this, most mentioned solution is to use Spring DATA JPA Projections ([ref](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections))

I did the following:

```
public interface FindAllBookProjection {

    String getFirst();

    List<PageProjection> getPages();

    interface PageProjection {
        Integer getNumber();
    }
}
```

The issue with projections is that they cause the famous N+1 select problem as the pages are loaded lazily.

I also couldn't find a way to use projections with @Query in the @Repository for the nested properties.

There are other mentions online to use @EntityGraph. From what I understand @EntityGraph will not work as it also selects all properties, specifying only what Entity associations should be loaded.

There are also suggestions on using other libraries like Blaze Persistence ([ref](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage)) or Hibernate's ResultTransformer ([ref](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-resulttransformer/)) . I would prefer to use only Spring DATA JPA instead of introducing another library for this functionality and writing ResultTransformers seems like adding a lot of boilerplate code to the mix.

To summarize my question is **what is the best way to choose what properties are selected for @Entity associations**. The main goal is to avoid pulling unnecessary amount of data from the database. The given example above is for demonstration, the data that I am working on includes over 10 columns and spans across 3-4 entities. Having control over the data means better performance.

Answer (score 2):

I am the creator of Blaze-Persistence and I can tell you that if there were an easy way to do this, I would not have created Entity-Views. You can read some of the [articles I wrote about this](https://blazebit.com/blog.html) and you will realize that doing this yourself, like you already figured, will require lots of boilerplate code. Doing this efficiently, will require even more code and in the end, you will probably end up with a solution that is inferior to Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views in one way or another and has probably no documentation.

Spring Data Projections is just limited and as I tried to outline many times before, Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views is like Spring Data Projections on steroids.

If you have "just" one or two simple mappings, you might be able to get this done by introducing special `@Immutable @Entity`, maybe even with `@Subselect` in this particular case to model what you need, but believe me, this only works good on a small scale. Apart from that, Blaze-Persistence which works on top of JPA/Hibernate enables the use of a lot of advanced SQL features, which you usually can't use from within plain JPA/Hibernate.

Comment: What do you think about `select new EntityVew(...)` jql syntax?

Comment: Not sure how that would help as you'd still have to tie your query to the final representation. One of the major goal of Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views is to decouple business logic from representation/projection logic, but embedding entity views into a query would go against that.

Comment: But doesn't the whole View idea ruin decoupling of data layer from application layer? Because views are primarily dependent on application logic

Comment: You need a DTO for as representation on your application/representation layer, so you create that. Of course that representation is related to your data, because you want to be able to map your data to it. Is that coupling? Of course not, it's just how things work. Entity-Views just let's you annotate that DTO in a way that allows you to efficiently read data in the format you are expecting.

Comment: I'm not sure if I may ask this kind of question here, but does blaze-persistence-integration-spring-data work with jakarta or spring boot 3? Becase I'm trying to play around with it to figure out how to use it in my other project, and it doesn't seem to work so nicely. Right now I'm running into integration module requiring javax.persistence.EntityManager, when as I said my project uses jakarta

Comment: Doesn't work yet. I'm still working on upgrading. You can follow the progress here: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/issues/1649

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, ORM libraries should use whole objects, that means loading all data into the program and then transforming/filtering according to logic.

For specific use-cases, where performance is really hindered, I'd use entities in
the database, such as Views/Procedures.

In your case, i'd create a View:

```
CREATE VIEW book_content as 
SELECT book.first as [first],
       array_agg(page.content || ' ') as [content]
FROM book
LEFT JOIN page
       ON page.book_id = book.id
GROUP BY book.first
```

And then create a @Repository and @Entity for it in spring.